# Remove an object from array by key

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this array :

```
this.menuItems = [
        {
            category: 'category 4',
            items: [
                {
                    type: 'link',
                    icon: '',
                },
                {
                    type: 'link',
                    icon: '',
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            category: 'category 1',
            items: [
                {
                    type: 'text',
                    icon: 'pencil'
                },
                {
                    type: 'checkbox',
                    icon: 'pencil'
                },
            ]
        },
```

I want to delete the object from `menuItems` that have type = `checkbox`.
I tried like this :

```
this.menuItems.forEach(category => {
            category.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                if (item.type === 'checkbox') {
                    category.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
        });
```

But not working. Can you help me please with some advices ? Thx in advance

Comment: None of your object has ```type : checkbox``` property .. Can you recheck the data?

Comment: items got updated (there will be still some bugs, but not in the example you provided). I believe change detection is not called properly. could you provide a code where these items are rendered?

Answer (score 5):

1. [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
2. [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const menuItems = [
    {
        category: 'category 4',
        items: [
            {
                type: 'link',
                icon: '',
            },
            {
                type: 'link',
                icon: '',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        category: 'category 1',
        items: [
            {
                type: 'text',
                icon: 'pencil',
            },
            {
                type: 'checkbox',
                icon: 'pencil',
            },
        ],
    },
];

const result = menuItems.map(item => ({ ...item, items: item.items.filter(i => i.type !== 'checkbox') }));

console.log(result);
```